# How can I "remove" variability in my data that is due to periodic signals, such as Temperature, RH and Solar radiation?

Tags: python, seasonality, signal-processing, signal-detection, multiple-seasonalities

I have a measured signal that I know is affected by some periodic signals, such as Temperature, RH and Solar radiation.

Is there a way that I can "remove" their influence from my measured signal?

Comment: I guess RH means relative humidity. Ideally the periodicity may not be an issue, as the main idea may just be to identify the dependence through a regression-type model. But the time series aspect will be crucial if there are time delays in the relationship between environmental variables and measured signal. Also, are you looking at daily or yearly cycles  or both?

Comment: Nick's question is a good one: in what frequencies are you interested? And what are the frequencies of the signals you don't want? You could probably implement some digital filters to get what you want - perhaps a low-pass filter if your undesired signals are higher frequency than the desired signal.

Comment: Well, I look at all cycles. Mainly daily and weekly are of interest.